# Flutter - Scroll controller is not getting listened

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on Pagination in flutter and the **_scrollController.addListener** is not working. And it is not showing me any errors.

**Here is the code**

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getContacts();
    _scrollController.addListener(
      () {
        double maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
        double currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
        double delta = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25;

        if (maxScroll - currentScroll < delta) {
          _getMoreContacts();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Here is the code that has been called in **_scrollController.AddListener**

```
 _getMoreContacts() async {
    print('getting more contacts called');
    if (_moreContactsAvailable == false) {
      print('no more contacts');
      return;
    }

    if (_gettingMoreContacts == true) {
      return;
    }
    _gettingMoreContacts = true;
    Query q = firestore
        .collection('Phonebook')
        .orderBy('name')
        .startAfter([_lastDocument.data()['name']]).limit(_perPage);
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await q.get();

    if (querySnapshot.docs.length < _perPage) {
      _moreContactsAvailable = false;
    }
    _lastDocument = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];
    contacts.addAll(querySnapshot.docs);
    setState(() {});
    _gettingMoreContacts = false;
  }
```

Comment: Did you initialize it? _scrollController = ScrollController();

Answer (score 0):

The `controller` must be assigned to some scrolling widgets like `ListView`, `GridView` etc

Example:

```
    ListView(
          controller: _scrollController,
```

Assign, controller to respective scrolling widget, then this should work.

Comment: I have already assigned that to listview and scrolling works fine, but when It comes to pagination **_scrollcontroller.addListener** is not working in the initstate function.

Comment: I have edited the question, I have added the code that is getting called inside _scrollController.addListener

Comment: us addListener() gets called while scrolling? that is the main question put print statement and check

Comment: Yes I did that and It is not printing the statement.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62594443/flutter-listview-builder-scroll-controller-listener-not-firing-inside-list-view